Forecasting via Average IF Function & Trend on Google Sheet with Horizontal Data
So I'm trying to forecast my yearly targets and as my BP is horizontally oriented in rows I am trying to accomodate for gaps and skip total's of cells to get a custom range, but nothing is working.
Issue 1:
=AVERAGEIF(TRANSPOSE({$EM$3:$EX$3,$FA$3:$FL$3}),FO$3,TRANSPOSE({$EM$4:$EX$4,$FA$4:$FL$4}))
This is not returning a value even though it should, even without the transpose it just says 'Argument must be a Range'
Issue 2:
=AVERAGEIF({$EM$3:$EX$3,$FA$3:$FL$3},FO$3,{$EM$4:$EX$4,$FA$4:$FL$4})/AVERAGE($FA$4:$FL$4,$EM$4:$EX$4)*TREND({$EM$4:$EX$4,$FA$4:$FL$4},{$EM$1:$EX$1,$FA$1:$FL$1},FO$1)
I am not able to capture the Trend Forecast in a row. Need help with this!
I tried the Filter function to join ranges but that doesn't work in this scenario, I am hoping to keep my formating to get this formula adjusted as there are mutiple more Spreadsheets I need this one formula to apply on and I won't be able to accomodate the formating for each of them.

share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output
